# Create unique ID for cells in a field using random number generator

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a field (column) with 2,700 records (including duplicates). The field has 263 unique records (all values are text).

I want to generate random numbers between 1-263 in a new field such that the same random number shows adjacent to duplicates. For example:

If I have the following text values `A,A,A,B,B,C` then the following random numbers can be generated in the adjacent field respectively `2,2,2,1,1,3`.

How might I achieve this?

Comment: Does it need to be random for any particular reason? Can't you just sort the field so that all the duplicates are together and in the next column use an if formula to increment a counter if the row prior is different?

Comment: Yes, I want to pick a random sample. If I sort it, then how will I get a random sample

Answer (score 0):

*Create unique ID* and *same random number* strictly are not compatible, but a distinct 'arbitrary' allocation of numbers in sets is possible with use of a random number generator and without disturbing the order of the data.

Extract a list of the 263 unique values, say with Advanced Filter, Copy to another location, Unique records only. In cells next to each cell of that extract add:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,999)
```

Sort the range occupied by the extract/formula pairs by the formula results. Index the resulting extract cells list from `1` to `263` and use the resulting table_array to lookup the index numbers corresponding to the entries in your data.

The resulting IDs will keep changing each time the sheet is refreshed unless the formulae are converted to their results, such as with select, Copy, Paste Special..., Values.